# Changing the color of StatusBar, Toolbar and TabLaylout in fragment properly

Tags: android

Actually I want to change color of `TabLayout`, `StatusBar` and `Toolbar` every time.

I change fragment like:

- fragment1: blue
- fragment2: red
- fragment3: yellow
- fragment 4: orange.

Color is changing but not according to given by me, it picked color randomly.
I create a method "changeHeader()" in main and call that method in fragments.

Main Activity Method

```
public void changeHeader(int toolbarcolor, int statusbarcolor, int tablayoutcolor) {
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(toolbarcolor);
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(tablayoutcolor);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(statusbarcolor);
    }
    navHeader.setBackgroundColor(tablayoutcolor);
}
```

Calling in Fragment 1

```
((Main)getActivity()).changeHeader(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.blue2),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.blue3)
        );
```

calling in Fragment 2

```
((Main)getActivity()).changeHeader(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.red1),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.red2),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.red3)
        );
```

Calling in Fragment 3

```
((Main)getActivity()).changeHeader(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow1),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow2),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow3)
        );
```

Calling in Fragment 4

```
((Main)getActivity()).changeHeader(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.orange1),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.orange2),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.orange3)
        );
```

I called "changeHeader" in in onCreateView of fragment, please provide solution for me.

Comment: In `onAttach()` method get your activity reference and call your `chageHeader()` method.

Comment: yes if you do call to the `changeHeader()` method in `onAttach()` of fragment, it will ensure that when the fragment is created and attached to the activity then it will do call this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your tab layout, it initializes three tabs at once (current, previous and next). You should create a PageChangeListener and add it to your ViewPager.

Create PageChangeListener

```
public class DetailOnPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

    private int currentPage;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        currentPage = position;
        String colorCode = "#FFFFFF";
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                colorCode = "#FF0000";
                break;
            case 1:
                colorCode = "#00FF00";
                break;
            case 2:
                colorCode = "#0000FF";
                break;
            case 3:
                colorCode = "#33BCFD";
                break;
            case 4:
                colorCode = "#F44CFD";
                break;
            case 5:
                colorCode = "#FAB55D";
                break;
            case 6:
                colorCode = "#6ABCF6";
                break;
            case 7:
                colorCode = "#F777FD";
                break;
            case 8:
                colorCode = "#FAB888";
                break;
            case 9:
                colorCode = "#999CFD";
                break;
            case 10:
                colorCode = "#F00CFD";
                break;
        }
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeHeader(colorCode);
    }

    public final int getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }
}
```

Add Listener to your ViewPager

```
DetailOnPageChangeListener myPageChangeListener = new DetailOnPageChangeListener();
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(myPageChangeListener);
```

Remove Listener in destroy method

```
mViewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(myPageChangeListener);
```

changeHeader method in you MainActivity should look like this

```
public void changeHeader(String toolbarcolor) {
    this.getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(toolbarcolor)));
}
```